# Inserting Angular 2 [routerLink] attribute to an html anchor in Typescript(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

I am making a dynamic menu and I am trying to manually insert attribute [routerLink]='[URL]' in an HTMLAnchorElement element:

```
var linkNode = document.createElement("a");
```

I tried `linkNode.setAttribute('[routerLink]', "['"+url+"']");`

but I get: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[routerLink]' is not a valid attribute name.

Any suggestions of a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This cannot be done this way. It is not a valid attribute as it is actually a custom Angular2 binding directive, but you already know that. Dynamic routes shouldn't be built by `document.createElement`, instead create a template.

Comment: Thanks David! I am looking into using DynamicComponentLoader, I'll see if it fits my purpose. It is for a dynamic menu that I am building, where at run time based on user role the menu items get populated. Any more suggestions are welcome. Cheers